# Execute a network script at wake-up with systemd (15.04)

Tags: network-manager, wakeup, systemd

I would like to connect my VPN after wake-up.

**1)** I have created a script in my home (wakeup.sh)

```
#! /bin/bash
(echo "Sortie de veille: lancement de wakeup le $(date '+%d/%m/%Y a %H:%M')"
sleep 30
nmcli con up id "My_id_xxxxxx"
echo "-------------------END LOG-------------------") 2>&1 | tee -a /home/guillaume/sortie_veille_auto.log
```

**2)** I have created a service in /etc/systemd/system/ named wakeup.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run user script after suspend
After=basic.target
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target

[Service]
User=guillaume
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/home/guillaume/wakeup

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
```

**3)** Then, I have activated it with

```
systemctl enable wakeup.service
```

and

```
systemctl status wakeup.service
```

to verify.

**4)** After a try, the script is launched, but I have this error in the log:

```
Erreur : l'activation de la connexion a échoué : Not authorized to control networking.
```

What's wrong ? nmcli can work with a normal user.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having separate `After` and `WantedBy`, put them in a series like:

```
After=basic.target suspend.target hibernate.target
WantedBy=basic.target suspend.target hibernate.target
```

At least that worked for me. I'm not sure what the `basic.target` is, but I use the other two successfully like I've shown.