# Help with g810-led, actually g213-led and g203-led. Setting up a service

Tags: keyboard, mouse, suspend, systemd

I'm synchronizing my keyboard leds to cycle color with my mouse this way: `cd /home/&USER/Docuemnts/g203-led; sudo g213-led -fx cycle all 20000ms && sudo ./g203-led.py cycle 20000;`

here there are instructions to set a service: [How do I run a single command at startup using systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd)

Github to g203-led: https://github.com/smasty/g203-led

I want to setup a service that run at startup and on wake. But the problem I have is that the g203-led is not part of Ubuntu software. I don't know if I should do `cd path/to/script` in a service or if there are better ways to set this up.

I guess the service would look like this but I don't see targets for wake-up from suspend.

**Service file**

```
[Unit]
Description=Logitech led service

[Service]
ExecStart=sudo /home/$USER/Documents/g203-led/leds-start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target, wakeup.target
```

**Sh file**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/&USER/Documents/g203-led;
g213-led -fx cycle all 20000ms && /home/$USER/Documents/g203-led/g203-led.py cycle 20000;
```

Found this: [Run a command as su after every wake from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083719/run-a-command-as-su-after-every-wake-from-suspend)

So my last question would if someone can help set it up in a more clean manner if possible because I think being it on Home folder it is delaying it and making the keyboard and mouse not sync properly. Autostart works fine but it won't work on wake from suspend. I know g203-led is out of Ubuntu repos but if someone is kind to help me anyways.

**Current service file**

```
[Unit]
Description=Logitech led service
After=basic.target suspend.target hibernate.target
[Service]
User=Root
ExecStart=/home/&USER/Documents/g203-led/leds-start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target basic.target suspend.target hibernate.target
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Logitech G203 Lightsync mouse with the following (20.04):

Install **ratbagd** (system daemon to introspect and modify configurable mice):

```
sudo apt install ratbagd
```

Install [Piper](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.freedesktop.Piper):

```
 flatpak install flathub org.freedesktop.Piper
```

[Add the missing mouse id](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/issues/1014#issuecomment-651408692) to /usr/share/libratbag/logitech-g102-g203.device

DeviceMatch=usb:046d:c084;usb:046d:c092

Restart **ratbagd**

```
sudo systemctl restart ratbagd.service
```

Run **Piper**, and I was able to set resolution, buttons and RGB effects.